# Visa picture with bandage/wound

Tags: visas, usa

I have a US visa appointment in a few days, and I'll have a *very* minor surgery in my forehead a few days before. So I'll have somewhat of a scar and a bandage covering it. The doctor told me that it's perfectly OK to take out the bandage for a little while for the picture.

Would the workers at the ASC complain / cancel my application if I have a minor scar/wound on my face?

I doubt it (if I fall on my face while walking to my appointment, that shouldn't be cause for cancellation), but someone might know better :)

**UPDATE:** Everything went fine. The ASC worker was a bit doubtful on whether embassy would accept the picture with a bandage. She asked me whether I wanted to reschedule or try anyway, so I removed the bandage and took the picture with the tiny scar. (I guess I could have also been allowed to try with the bandage on, I don't quite remember.) She did mention "you're supposed to look the same way as when you'll be traveling", which sounded a bit shady to me since some visas last 10 years.

Here's a (very crappy) picture of my bandage as it was that day

[image]

Later, the consular officer did not give a crap about it, and didn't even mention it. This was not my first visa, I have a B1/B2 and this is the second J1 I'm applying for, so maybe that made a difference. Also, this was in Argentina which has one of the lowest US visa rejection rates in the world (maybe the lowest).

Comment: Phone them up and ask?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found [this](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/118561/photographic-standards.pdf). It is not the US policy, but my expectation would be that this is a common standard at least in the western world.

> ...if there are clear medical reasons, for example, head wounds, hair
>   loss through medical treatment or illness, a scarf or bandage can be
>   accepted as long as it does not cover the face.

To my knowledge, face recognition software usually does not use a forehead as a defining feature. Neither do people who verify pictures (e.g. border guards) in IDs are trained to do since forehead can be covered by hair.

Comment: Purely an anecdote, but my iPhone X recognizes me with and without a hat on (which comes down to just above my eyebrows)